# Is there a way to send timeseries data along with a scheduled email?

Tags: report, scheduler, thingsboard

Hi I hope you are all doing well.

I am currently trying to send data under a customers telemetry inside the body of an email using the scheduler and its rule chain with no luck so far. Basically I want to send a report of the dashboard once every 30 days but I want to add extra information (which can be found under the customers telemetry) into the body. Editing the body and adding text is easy but I am just unable to get a rule which allows me to fetch the customers telemetry. I have tried using enrichment blocks and a couple of other stuff but I think because the originator isn't the user itself or at least related to the user I can't fetch the telemetry. Please if you have any advice/recommendation on what I can attempt it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When sending the report from a new rule chain without using a scheduler but instead using a message from a device or perhaps a count alarms function in the rule chain you can use blocks to manipulate the data and add what you want to the message. this can also be done in the default report rule chain but it can't be done with a scheduled event as to my knowledge.

Hope this helps anyone who has this question in the future.